# How we can use like and limit together in a sql query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE 'b%' limit 3;
```

gives the following error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'City LIKE 'b%' limit 3'.
```

Comment: [Your query in mysql works as-is](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ebd1c/1). Voting to close as "cannot reproduce".

Comment: Please check which RDBMS you are using. Based on error message I doubt that it is MySQL.

Comment: Does ms-access has limit???  NO.  So why do you put `LIMIT`on your query????

Comment: I was studying for sql on w3school where I get this error. While in some other queries running on w3school editor limit was working fine, but in this query the editor is showing error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message indicates that you are using MS Access. You need to use `TOP` instead of `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Customers
WHERE City LIKE 'b%'
-- ORDER BY some_column'; -- to get stable results
```

Comment: Really. In MySql?

Comment: @AlanHay I am 100% sure that question is incorrectly tagged with `MySQL`

Comment: Yes, Lukasz you are right but limit was working fine in other queries but here with like '.....' it was showing error

Comment: can anyone please tell me a good source to learn sql and dbms.

Comment: @PratyushSharma It highly depends on RDBMS (Oracle/PostgreSQL/SQL Server/MySQL). In general I suggest old-fashioned way i.e. books . I started with 
"T-SQL Fundamentals" by Itzik Ben-Gan. After you get fundamentals there is only practice :) Good luck